# Using event arguments in portable class library

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-phone-8, portability, eventargs

I'm currently developing an application for both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8. The building of the views has to be very dynamic, so I have to use a lot of datatemplates for this. In these data templates I use the Galasoft MVVMLight EventToCommand and because I need the event arguments, I also use PassEventArgsToCommand="True".

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=SelectionChangedCommand}" 
                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

The problem is, that the classes where I need to use these event arguments (where my commands take place) must be in a portable class library, therefore I cannot use platform specific event arguments in these classes.

```
private void SelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs sel)
{
     //do something
}
```

In my case I have to use SelectionChangedEventArgs, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs and KeyEventArgs.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reflection and it did work.

```
string keyCode = "";

        if (args != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo p = args.GetType().GetProperty("Key");
            keyCode = p.GetValue(args, null).ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

after i lots of trying, i finally find my solution.
Like user1545884, i use Reflection too, but GetValue method does not work for me
SelectedItem object comes in "AddedItems" collection so i GetProperty method with "AddedItems"
and i foreach in that until find my object in it.

```
IEnumerable ie = (parameter.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("AddedItems").GetValue(parameter) as IEnumerable);
foreach (var item in ie)
{
    if (item is Store_Province)
    {

    }
}
```